# Mylyn Git Connector GitHub Pull Requests Repository Task Window Missing Pull Request Fields

Tags: eclipse, github, egit, mylyn

I am trying to set up my Eclipse environment with EGIT and the Mylyn GIT Connector such that everything I need to do can be done from within the Eclipse IDE (as opposed to having to swap over to Github.com or the Git command line interface). I have successfully installed the Mylyn Git Connector plug-in and have successfully created a Mylyn GitHub Pull Requests repository (have validated the credentials).

There is not much in the form of documentation but supposedly in order to create a Pull Request to the remote repository I need to create what is called a "repository task" (as opposed to a "local task"), by selecting the GitHub Pull Requests repository, and then being presented with a window that is specific to the selected repository type (in this case a GitHub Pull Request). However, I keep being presented with a window that does not contain necessary pull request specific fields and thus the submit of the pull request fails with the following error:
    Submit failed. Unexpected error: Invalid request.
    "base", "head" weren't supplied.
There are no fields in the Repository Task/Pull Request Task window to allow for entry of the base and head values.
If anyone has been able to configure EGIT/Mylyn to enable creation of Pull Requests, please advise as to how you went about configuring your environment.